# Undefined reference with extern C

Tags: c++, c, open-source, makefile, signal-processing

I am trying to compile a program with Netbeans (g++) that inlcudes Aquila, [an open source libary](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila). I followed [the installation instructions](http://aquila-dsp.org/download/).

But when trying to compile a small test program, I get this error

```
In function `Aquila::OouraFft::fft(double const*)':OouraFft.cpp:(.text+0x24f):
undefined reference to `cdft'
```

OouraFft.h:

```
#include "Fft.h"

extern "C" {
    void cdft(int, int, double *, int *, double *); //prototypes of offending function
    void rdft(int, int, double *, int *, double *); //second one.
}
```

The C file in the libs folder contains the definition of the functions.

The line that cause the actual error in 
OouraFft.cpp:

```
// let's call the C function from Ooura's package
    cdft(2*N, -1, a, ip, w);
```

So I am thinking the external C file is not being linked with the project but included all the directories in the project directory.
I have been googling for hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: have header file for that C file? yes then try with `extern "C" {
#include "MyCHeader.h"
}`

Comment: Actually this looks like a link error not a compile error. Have you remembered to add a link option for your library? EG if it's called `libfft` you will want to add `-lfft` to the link line. Even if you have a single source file and think you are just compiling, you will be linking (perhaps as part of the compile step) and need to specify which libraries to link to.

Answer (score 5):

Up to git version 6f5d6b, Aquila's CMake config will generate static library by default. You should copy `/path-to-your-build-tree/lib/libOoura_fft.a` to `/path-to-your-install-dir/lib/`, and link it to your test program.

Comment: You'll also have to make sure ooura_fft is linked within your library...I ran into the same problem and thought the ooura_fft stuff would be included within libAquila.a. So copy libOoura_fft.a to your lib directory, and include -looura_fft in your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

As Answeror said you need to put libOoura_fft.a in the right place (`/usr/local/lib` is the default for `libAquila.a`).

You also need to link to it as  Chris Vandevelde said, but you should link to `-lOoura_fft` (first "O" capital). You should be linking with `-lAquila` as well

Just wanted to clarify.